# Two JQuery questions about this fiddle

Tags: jquery, css

Two questions about this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/4emqh/2/

1) Originally, the black box (with div id "cloud")moves to the right and you can drag it into the pink box. However, when I tried to add a second box (in green) with div id "cloud2", it stopped the animation of the black. You can see in the fiddle how I tried to add green/cloud2. What is the right way to do it?  I thought you can stack elements beside each other (with a comma or semi colon) like I did with #cloud and #cloud2 in this fiddle.

2) when the black box is dragged into the pink box, the pink box gives a message "dropped" in black letters. Is there a way to change the color of the message to make it white, for example?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

http://jsfiddle.net/4emqh/5/

When you select multiple items in a single selector, your selectors should be joined with comma and all one string. (e.g. `$("#item1, #item2")`)

---

You probably want to add a class that specifies a white color, but this in the drop function will achieve what you want as an example of 'a way' to do it:

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight")
           .css("color", "white")
           .find("p")
           .html("Dropped!");
```

**quick edit**

BumbleB2na's suggesting of adding a class (or otherwise selecting in css) the `p` tag is much cleaner.

Comment: was just going to type this but you beat me to it.

Comment: thanks a lot, the second part of the question (which maybe you didn't see or wasn't clear enough) is changing the color of the "dropped" message. Is that possible.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do it like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/4emqh/6/

Comment: +1, I think this answers part of the question, which is, 'what is the right way to do this`.

Comment: thanks a lot, the second part of the question (which maybe you didn't see or wasn't clear enough) is changing the color of the "dropped" message. Is that possible.

Comment: <div id="droppable">
    <p class="dropText"></p>
</div>

Comment: and css:  .dropText { color: white; }

Comment: o.k, thanks for answering. I rolled a die to decide which of you two get the "accepted answer" and Marc won. sorry.

Comment: Haha well that's good. I was in favour of Marc's answers anyways!